# Is there a way to rename menu items in Firefox?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, menu-bar, firefox, shortcut-menu

Google Chrome has a keyboard shortcut that I really like, `command + shift + B`. It hides and shows the bookmarks toolbar so I can use a new tab extension without worrying where my bookmarks are going to be when I need them.

I want some equivalent in Firefox, but the **keyboard shortcuts menu** in System Preferences>Keyboard>Shortcuts **doesn't work** because there are two exact instances of `Bookmarks Toolbar` in the Firefox menu bar: one under `View>Toolbars>Bookmarks Toolbar` and another one under `Bookmarks>Bookmarks Toolbar`.

Even though the one under `Bookmarks>Bookmarks Toolbar` isn't a selection, the custom command only begins to work when I go into File>View>Bookmarks Toolbar and select the option I'm trying to get a shortcut for in the first place.

I found an inkling on [this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/132786/is-there-a-way-to-rename-menu-items-in-mac) about renaming the file from the `mainmenu.nib` file, but the idea about doing that for Firefox was shot down in the same line it was suggested:

> some apps, like Firefox, won't have one at all.

...And so now I'm here, looking for some help. Does anyone know if Firefox has a `.nib` file equivalent for its' menu bar? Is there somewhere I could go in `about:config`?

Someone out there has the magic solution that I'm overlooking. I just need help finding it.

Comment: @Allan It seems someone needs to review the Help Center themselves. Please read the following line in [Asking - Topics](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): "third-party hardware, services and software when associated for use with Apple products". This question is perfectly valid, by the writing at least.

Comment: @RushilSrivastava - this question is essentially about *changing* Firefox to meet the needs of a particular user.  It's a Firefox issue; macOS is merely the current operating environment.  The same menus exist in the Windows and BSD/Linux versions as well.

Comment: @Allan This question is about software running on macOS, so it's perfectly on-topic here. It's probably also on-topic on other sites (including the Firefox/Mozilla Community site) but I don't see a reason to close it here. If you want to discuss a change of the Help Center guidelines please raise it on Meta.